# Migrating dotnet-isolated process Azure Function from .net 5 to .net 6

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0

I am trying to migrate my existing .net 5 `dotnet-isolated` function to .net 6. It is deployed to Azure. I updated all NuGet packages and set up `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `~4`. As mentioned, it's been working fine with .net 5 in `dotnet-isolated FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` setting, which is still present now.

It runs fine in Visual Studio 2022 but when deployed to Azure, no functions are loaded and executed. Functions app is up and running. With Kudu debug console I get:

```
2021-12-20T15:25:11.703 [Information] Loading functions metadata
2021-12-20T15:25:11.704 [Information] 0 functions loaded
2021-12-20T15:25:11.705 [Information] Loading functions metadata
2021-12-20T15:25:11.705 [Information] 0 functions loaded
2021-12-20T15:25:26.229 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "testname",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "4.0.1.16815",
  "versionDetails": "4.0.1+d22b332c30efafeed1e4898c9b92280697138194",
  "platformVersion": "96.0.7.599",
  "instanceId": "25d4009bce1d0f8d31e51726fdcef27cc4654e363649d28127051edda8891d94",
  "computerName": "10-30-6-202",
  "processUptime": 51200
}
```

Are functions with dotnet-isolated and .net 6 already supported on Azure? What else can I check to find out why no functions are found and executed?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly We created the ***.Net 5 Isolated v3 Azure Functions*** and deployed them in Azure through Visual Studio.

[image]

After deployed in Azure, we see the following configurations in the portal:

[image]

and run the functions:

[image]

After this step, change the .Net Core Version from **5** to **6** and functions version `v3` to `v4` in the `.csproj` file and rebuild the solution.

- It was built successfully and executed locally as well.

After changing version to **6**, published to same function app through the visual studio as it asked to update azure functions version automatically and selected Yes and published.

[image]

Here in the Azure Function App Configuration, it automatically changed the function version to `4`:

[image]

#### Updated Answer

**Published 2 functions in azure:**

[image]

**Published 0 function in azure:**

[image]

- Make sure you added your functions and published into azure to see
  the published functions are running/available in Function tab.
- After publishing the function app to azure you may **Changed/ Deleted** **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** value. If you changed or removed in Application Configuration the functions in function tab are removed in the portal.

We encountered the same issue when we change the **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** value **0** in application Configuration. We see the same debug console log

[image]

**Note:**

1. If you made that change **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** make that before publishing into azure.
   Or
   Publish the function app without **zip deploy** in using visual to azure.
2. If you made any change **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** please make sure your **function class files**  available in function tab

Comment: Thank you for your response. My function app is also up and running, but no functions are found and executed. The rest in configuration is the same as on your side (FUNCTIONS_EXTENSIONS_VERSION is ~4 and FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME is also dotnet-isolated).

Comment: @JanezLukan, Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again for helping DelliganeshS-MT. There seems to be a problem within our Azure DevOps build agent which manages to build and deploy, but for some strange reason something is wrong and not working, even when functions are successfully deployed and up & running. Deployment from Visual Studio is successful and works as expected.